# How to disable navigation drawer menu button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, menuitem

What i want here when i move to another `Fragment` by clicking in `NavigationDrawer` menu button then button should be disabled.

Because `addToBackStack();` method add multiple times in their stack when click again and again. So wanted to disable it when i move to another fragment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35818397/4409113 Or setting it as disabled maybe ..

Answer (score 5):

To disable **toggle button** in navigation drawer use

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

to enable use `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN` replacing `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED`

To disable **drawer item** click

1. Refer [Hide Some Navigation Drawer Menu Item - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954993/hide-some-navigation-drawer-menu-item-android/35818397#35818397)  there you can hide it
2. If you do not wish to  hide in `onNavigationItemSelected` where you check `(id == R.id.whatevertheitemid)` also use a Boolean to allow access as you wish

eg

```
if (id == R.id.whatevertheitemid && isAccessGiven) { // do your task
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its helps me to solve this issue:

```
     @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
              int id = item.getItemId();

     if(id==R.id.nav_item1){   //use can write your menu item here
         return false;
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to disable menu item:

```
NavigationView navigationView;

navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Now in menu item click:

```
Menu menuView= navigationView.getMenu();
menuView.getItem(ID).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now i think its not good way to disabling menuItem. Is there any other to do so that if fragment is already open then it will not addToBackStack().

Comment: Try to check fragment instance. If it is null then open fragment otherwise do not allow click action

Answer (score 1):

**in kotlin:**

```
navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.your_target_item_id).setEnabled(false)
```

this is work for me and disabled item in drawerToggle menu

**in Java:**

```
NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
navigation.getMenu().getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_target_item_id).setEnabled(false);
```